# What is meant by "let the subspace topology $A \subset X$ be discrete"

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to find out what is meant by this statement. Discrete topology is when every subset of $X$ is open.

(1) It appears to me that what is meant is that no matter what the topology on $X$ is every set of the form $Y \cap U$ where $U $ is open in $X$ is open in $Y$.

(2) Or is the subspace topology when $X$ is discrete topology meant?

If what is meant is (1), that confuses me. Because it simply implies that a topology can be of two different characteristics: discrete and subspace at the same time for instance. Which doesn't seem appealing to me.

If it is (2), then no problem.

Or is something else meant?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: They might mean to consider the inclusion of sets $A \to X$ as a continuous map, where $X$ has its own topology and $A$ has the discrete topology. This guarantees that any map $A \to X$ is continuous. But yes, that does seem like a confusing sentence, some context would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding number (1) is correct.

**Example :** Consider $\Bbb R$ with usual topology.

Then the subspace $\Bbb Z$ of $\Bbb R$ has actually discrete topology on it. That is, subspace topology on $\Bbb Z$ = Discrete topology.

To see this, observe that every singleton set $\{n\}=\Bbb Z \cap (n-1,n+1)$ where $(n-1,n+1)$ is an open interval in $\Bbb R$. Thus every singleton set is open in $\Bbb Z$. Which implies our assertion.